# Properly adding a Facebook jar in Eclipse for Blackberry

Tags: facebook, blackberry

How to add Facebook .jar file properly in eclipse for blackberry

```
"ERRO :Module 'FacebookBlackBerrySDK-v0.8.25' not found."
```

Comment: Please change the question title, because the question you explained and the title both are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the step to add the jar properly to your eclipse project. Its seems that you are not adding the jar properly in your eclipse environment. So check the step please.

- Create a folder called “lib” (or whatever you want to call it) under your project, and copy the downloaded JAR files into that folder.
- Right-click your project > Properties
- Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARs… > Choose the JAR files in the “lib” folder
- Java Build Path > Order and Export > Check the JAR files

Comment: at 1st time it not loads at the 2nd time it loads..but FB url loads a blank browser filed appears ?

Comment: okk have this solved your problem ?>??? And for your new query you can ask a new question